# Android端末でOnsenUI2.0.0のアプリ実行時にエラーが出てしまう

Tags: android, monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

こんにちは、先日リリースされたOnsenUI2.0.0（正式版）を使用してアプリを作成したいと考えています。

しかし、OnsenUI2.0.0を使用するとAndroid端末でエラーメッセージが表示されてしまいます。

エラー内容が「onsenui.min.js」のpromiseがcatchされていないということはわかりましたが、どう対処してよいか分かりません。

何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら回答をよろしくお願い致します。

【実行環境】

- 端末：Nexus7(2013)
- OS：Android4.4.2
- Monacaデバッガー6.0.1
- OnsenUI2.0.0(正式版)
- AngularJS1.4.3
- Cordova6.2.0

**※iPhone6　iOS9.3.5で実行したところエラーは表示されませんでした。**

【プロジェクトの作成手順】

1. MonacaIDEから「OnsenUI and Angular1」の「OnsenUI v2 Angular1 Navigation」のテンプレートを選択しプロジェクトを作成します。
2. ダウンロードしたOnsenUI2.0.0を「www/lib/onsenui」以下のファイルと差し替えます。（この時点で以下のメッセージが表示されます。）[image: メッセージ1]
3. 「JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除」から「ncmb」を検索し、「ncmb Ver=2.1.3」を追加します。（エラーが発生し以下のメッセージが表示されます。）[image: メッセージ2]

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 空のプロジェクトを作成し、`ファイル`→`JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除`を選択し、`Onsen UI(Monaca Version)`→`2.0.0`を選択する方法ではダメなんでしょうか？

Comment: oTakさんコメントありがとうございます。返答が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。そちらの方法も試してみましたが、同様のエラーが発生してしまいました。

Comment: 私の環境では問題ないですね。`lib`を参照している`SCRIPT`タグを削除し、`JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除`から`Onsen UI 2.0`を選択してみてください。

Comment: oTakさんコメントありがとうございます。新規プロジェクトを作成し、scriptタグの削除とコンポーネントの追加を行いましたが同様のエラーが出てしまいました。現在Android端末の環境が１つしかないため、この環境が良くないのかもしれません。

Comment: 自己解決しました。onsenUIアップデート後も同様のエラーが起きていましたが、WebViewに問題があると考えAndroidOSをアップデートしたところ、エラーが確認できなくなりました。また、4.4.2でもcrosswalkプラグインを使用することでエラーを回避できるようです。

Comment: 自己解決した場合、コメントではなく回答として記載した方がよろしいかと思います。